# How to print link map of running process?

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

How to print in a nice way dynamic loader's link map of running process in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Comment: yea, it's a process map. But dynamic linker has such internal list of link_map type which describes loaded shared objects and I mean that.

Comment: Oh, so you want to see the symbols resolved and all that other info, too? Not just the memory regions? Not sure of a simple way to do that...